# I am getting a 400 bad request while using google custom search with discord.js! what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript, google-api, discord.js, google-custom-search

I am building a discord bot which searches a query on google using the custom search api but i am getting this error! here's my code, what am i doing wrong?

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const request = require("node-superfetch");
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    name: 'google',
    description: "searches google ",
    cooldown: 10,
    permissions: [],
 async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord)  {
    let googleKey = "XXXX";
    let csx = "be4b47b9b3b849a71";
    let query = args.join(" ");
    let result;

    if(!query) return message.reply("Please enter a Valid Query");
    result = await search(query);
    if (!result) return message.reply("Invalid Search");

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTite(result.title) 
    .setDescription(result.snippet)
    .setImage(result.pagemap ? result.pagemap.cse_thumbnail[0].src : null)
    .setURL(result.link)
    .setColor(0x7289DA)
    .setFooter("Powered by Google")

    return message.channel.send(embed);

    async function search(query) {
        const { body } = await request.get("https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1").query({
            key: googleKey, cs: csx, safe: "off", q: query
        });

        if(!body.items) return null;
        return body.items[0];
        } 
    }
 }
```

ERROR MESSAGE: (node:10944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 400 Bad Request
at Request._request (D:\Coding\FLASH\node_modules\node-superfetch\index.js:58:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at async search (D:\Coding\FLASH\commands\google.js:31:26)
at async Object.execute (D:\Coding\FLASH\commands\google.js:17:14)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:10944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10944) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Shouldn't `.setTite(result.title)` be `.setTitle(result.title)` with an `l`?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full error message.

Comment: @DalmTo Done check now!!

Comment: @AndrewMorton No there's not a problem in that part! and sorry about the api key! i later put it in the env file but forgot to change here :(